# How to modify Java Build Path/Source using maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working on having all the configuration of a project managed by Maven instead of eclipse and I got stuck when I tried to change the Source from there.

**This is what I have:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsORs.png]

**And this is what I want:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKkgO.png]

How can I modify this using maven?

Thanks

Comment: It's almost always better to include pictures and code within your post so that our users don't have to leave the site to answer your question.

Comment: Please make sure your code is in the question as text and not a picture.

Answer (score 0):

With maven, [you can change all this configuration](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element) in the `<build>` tag :

```
 <build>
    <directory>target</directory>
    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
    <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>src/main/scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
      <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      </testResource>
    </testResources>
  </build>
```

That said, I think it would be better to copy your source files as maven intend it to avoid the hassle, from `src/` to `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources` depending on the type of file.